# How to stop SED from stripping the final line feed from text files

Tags: unix, sed

I am using sed to update various date formats within a text file and appending the result to another file.

The file dates are stored as YYYMMDD etc so I am replacing the YYYMMDD with the actual date.

The only issue is the final line of each file is missing a new line character, meaning the last and first lines are incorrectly aligned.

File 1:

```
00 YYMMDD TEST
05 3452256 MMDD 33456
80 File Trailer
```

File 2:

```
00 YYMMDD TEST
05 445674 MMDD 234456
80 File Trailer
```

What I need is the YYMMDD and MMDD updated with the current date and both files appended together like this:

```
00 180129 TEST
05 3452256 0129 33456
80 File Trailer
00 180129 TEST
05 445674 0129 234456
80 File Trailer
```

But what I am actually getting is:

```
00 180129 TEST
05 3452256 0129 33456
80 File Trailer00 180129 TEST
05 445674 0129 234456
80 File Trailer
```

Code:

```
YYYY=$(date +"%Y")
YY=$(date +"%y")
MM=$(date +"%m")
DD=$(date +"%d")
HH=$(date +"%H")
MI=$(date +"%M")
SS=$(date +"%S")
JJJ=$(date +"%j")

sed -- "s/yyyymmdd/$yyyyMMdd/g;s/yymmdd/$yyMMdd/g;s/mmdd/$mmdd/g;s/yyjjj/$yyjjj/g" "$full_path" >> $deploy_path
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and if here is an easy fix?

---

Edit

It turns out the problem was with the source files I was using. Specifically: the file trailers were missing a CRLF. So the code above is working fine.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand the question.. please try to create a smaller sample input/output with failing case... and create a sample that can be tested by copy pasting...  `yyyymmdd` is used in code but not present in sample input

Comment: I updated the question with hopefully better examples

Comment: ok, can you try an experiment? suppose the input files are named `f1` and `f2`... see what output you get with `a='XYZ'; b='ABC'; sed "s/YYMMDD/$a/g; s/MMDD/$b/g" f1 f2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first wanted to suggest to replace `"$full_path"` with `<(cat "$full_path"; echo)`, but than realized that your "$full_path" will have 2 files and my fix is for one file only.
You can use `sed` for appending a newline with `$s/$/\n/`, so change your command into

```
sed -- "\$s/$/\n/; s/yyyymmdd/$yyyyMMdd/g;s/yymmdd/$yyMMdd/g;s/mmdd/$mmdd/g;s/yyjjj/$yyjjj/g" "$full_path" >> $deploy_path
```